# Im using oracle 10g to create table but it is showing "ORA-00922: missing or invalid option" and in the query

Tags: java, oracle

I'm using oracle 10g to create table but it is showing "ORA-00922: missing or invalid option" and in the query at bottom sequence line for `.nextval` it is showing red mark line, from long time searching for it.

```
CREATE TABLE  "TICKET_TABLE" (  
"TKT_NUMBER" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,    
"TKT_STATUS" VARCHAR2(10),
"TKT_CLIENT" VARCHAR2(10),
"TKT_ASSIGN" VARCHAR2(15),
"TKT_PROJ" VARCHAR2(15),    
"TKT_SUB" VARCHAR2(100),    
"TKT_BODY" VARCHAR2(200),   
"USER_NAME" VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL ENABLE,    
CONSTRAINT "TICKET_TABLE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("TKT_NUMBER") ENABLE) /  
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "BI_TICKET_TABLE"   
before insert on "TICKET_TABLE" for each row   
begin 
   select "TICKET_SEQ".nextval into :NEW.TKT_NUMBER from dual;  
end;   
/ ALTER TRIGGER  "BI_TICKET_TABLE" ENABLE /
```

Comment: Welcome to Oracle, where error messages are almost useless. =) By the way, [this runs fine](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a49f0/1/0) in Oracle 11g, even when the sequence doesn't exist! Also, I NEVER go by red lines. More often than not, this is just SQL Developer being weird for me. Try running the commands individually to determine which one is actually throwing the error.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce in 10g, either, but I may have a hint: SQL Developer is prompting me to bind `:NEW` in the trigger. Not sure what's going on there. That could be a red herring, though. No way to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Use sequence name without double quotes

```
 select TICKET_SEQ.nextval
```

Comment: Do you have TICKET_SEQ sequence in your DB?

Comment: Yes i have created sequence table.

Answer (score 0):

You might have forgot to **create sequence "TICKET_SEQ"**.
Try queries in the below format,

CREATE TABLE "TICKET_TABLE"
  (
    "TKT_NUMBER" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "TKT_STATUS" VARCHAR2(10),
    "TKT_CLIENT" VARCHAR2(10),
    "TKT_ASSIGN" VARCHAR2(15),
    "TKT_PROJ"   VARCHAR2(15),
    "TKT_SUB"    VARCHAR2(100),
    "TKT_BODY"   VARCHAR2(200),
    "USER_NAME"  VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    CONSTRAINT "TICKET_TABLE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("TKT_NUMBER") ENABLE
  );

**CREATE sequence "TICKET_SEQ" minvalue 1 maxvalue 100 increment BY 1 start with 10;**

SET define OFF;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "BI_TICKET_TABLE" before
  INSERT ON "TICKET_TABLE" FOR EACH row BEGIN
  SELECT TICKET_SEQ.nextval INTO :NEW.TKT_NUMBER FROM dual;
END;

ALTER TRIGGER "BI_TICKET_TABLE" ENABLE;

Comment: That resulted in the error `PL/SQL: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist` for me, not the one the OP reported. It was paired with a `PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored`, but not the one the OP mentioned. Could that be minor or patch version differences?

Comment: It may depends upon the version of the GUI that the OP is using, try put ';' at end of each statement and execute.